# Assigning a set of data in pandas dataframe to a set of states (intervals)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas.DataFrame which looks like this:

```
        mean       std
0   0.123933  0.012185
1   0.119992  0.023833
2   0.119150  0.005884
4   0.107363  0.014191
8   0.123733  0.017090
12  0.155717  0.021808
18  0.337767  0.029997
24  0.742300  0.094091
30  1.087750  0.175827
36  1.517833  0.196728
42  1.181283  0.179431
48  1.936333  0.102685
```

I want to assign each row to a state which is defined by intervals. i.e.

```
'''
Produce 11 numbers for 10 intervals between 0 and 2. 
i.e. first interval is between intervals[0] and intervals[1]
'''
intervals= numpy.linspace(0,2,11) 

>>>list(intervals)
[0.0,
 0.20000000000000001,
 0.40000000000000002,
 0.60000000000000009,
 0.80000000000000004,
 1.0,
 1.2000000000000002,
 1.4000000000000001,
 1.6000000000000001,
 1.8,
 2.0]
```

These states have labels, so `index=0` in the dataframe would belong to the first state (s1) ext.

What is the best way to implement this in python? I'm currently looking at `numpy.histogram`  but this gives the frequency in each bin, rather than the bin name.

The desired output would something like:

```
        mean       std    state
0   0.123933  0.012185    s1
1   0.119992  0.023833    s1
2   0.119150  0.005884    s1
4   0.107363  0.014191    s1
8   0.123733  0.017090    s1
12  0.155717  0.021808    s2
18  0.337767  0.029997    s2
24  0.742300  0.094091    s4
30  1.087750  0.175827    ...
36  1.517833  0.196728
42  1.181283  0.179431
48  1.936333  0.102685
```

Comment: How are you determining the state?  Are you just looking at the mean column and seeing which interval it's in?  If so, I don't get yout `s3` example?  The mean is `0.158350`, which should be `s1`?

Comment: Hi root. Thanks for pointing that out. Its an error. Your right, its which interval the mean is in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`pd.cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html):

```
# Define the state labels.
labels = ['s{}'.format(i) for i in range(1, len(intervals))]

# Perform the cut.
df['state'] = pd.cut(df['mean'], bins=intervals, labels=labels)
```

You may need to use some additional parameters of `pd.cut` depending on your exact use case (e.g. which endpoint of the interval you want to be included, etc.).

The resulting output:

```
        mean       std state
0   0.123933  0.012185    s1
1   0.119992  0.023833    s1
2   0.119150  0.005884    s1
4   0.107363  0.014191    s1
8   0.123733  0.017090    s1
12  0.155717  0.021808    s1
18  0.337767  0.029997    s2
24  0.742300  0.094091    s4
30  1.087750  0.175827    s6
36  1.517833  0.196728    s8
42  1.181283  0.179431    s6
48  1.936333  0.102685   s10
```